# Google Drive sync issues when unzipping nuScenes .tgz files using Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, synchronization, google-colaboratory

I have several large .tgz files, each close to 30GB (for the trainval split of the nuScenes dataset) stored on my Google Drive, and I am trying to unzip them using Google Colab by first mounting my Google Drive and then unzipping, as follows:

`from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive/", force_remount=True)

%cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/MSc Dissertation/data/sets/nuscenes
!tar -xzvf "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/MSc Dissertation/data/sets/nuscenes/v1.0-trainval08_blobs.tgz" -C "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/MSc Dissertation/data/sets/nuscenes-unzipped"`

In my Google Drive for nuScenes there are 10 "blobs" i.e. separate .tgz files as nuScenes is such a large dataset. In each case when I run the above, for whatever blob it is, it runs fine and the files are extracted within Colab itself, but when I open Google Drive in a Chrome tab, the same results are not reflected. They were reflected when I tried blob 10 (v1.0-trainval10_blobs.tgz) and with blob 9 (although some files with radar data, thankfully irrelevant for me as I only need camera and lidar data, were missing). With blob 8, in Colab all is unzipped, but Google Drive doesn't reflect this.

This seems to be an issue others have experienced:
[text](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/287)
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785726/google-drive-and-colaboratory-virtual-machine-are-not-syncing-properly)

I have tried, as suggested, using `drive.flush_and_unmount()`. The issue is this doesn't provide any verbose output so I am not sure if it is really working or not, the cell in Colab just stays running, with little output. Eventually one time it did actually show "Transport endpoint is not connected" and I wonder if this is because `/content/gdrive` disappears from the directory list, but in that case is it just unmounting or disconnecting before it's flushed? In which case would I not just see what should be flushed in my Google Drive?

Has anyone else had similar issues, especially with large files? Has `drive.flush_and_unmount()` eventually worked and does it just take a day or so to be reflected in Google Drive? If the Colab session were to time out with the `drive.flush_and_unmount()` cell still running would Google Drive still sync up eventually in the background due to some sort of backup?

One user LEBMD on the GitHub issue #287 seems to have had the same issue, but another user says eventually after 7hrs it worked. Can anyone share their experience or provide advice? You would think simple unzipping would be easier! (And by the way, it must be through Google Drive for me as I don't have space on my local system to accommodate such a large dataset, but I paid to expand my Google Drive to 2TB). Any help greatly appreciated!

TLDR: Google Colab unzipped files and Google Drive not syncing. `drive,flush_and_unmount()` runs for ages.